# Disappearing instance var

Tags: ruby

Here is my code:

```
class Klass
  ["thing", nil].each do |i|
    instance_variable_set("@#{i}reqs", {})
  end

  def initialize(var)
    @reqs[var] = self
  end
end

Klass.new("hello")
```

Which gives me the error:

in `initialize': undefined method`[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

I shouldn't be getting this error because the loop at the top should have initialized @reqs in it's second iteration. What is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instance variables belong to particular instances. That's why they are called instance variables.

In line 3, you set the instance variable called `@reqs` of the object `Klass`. In line 6, you access the instance variable called `@reqs` of an instance of the class `Klass`. Those are two *completely* different, distinct objects each with its own set of instance variables. Heck, those two objects don't even have the same *class*! (`Klass`'s class is `Class`, whereas `Klass.new`'s class is `Klass`.)

In line 6, `@reqs` is uninitialized, and uninitialized instance variables evaluate to `nil`.

There are many different ways to fix this, depending on your exact circumstances and requirements, the easiest way would be to initialize the instance variables in the `initialize` method, after all, that's what that method is there for:

```
class Klass
  def initialize(var)
    ['thing', nil].each do |i|
      instance_variable_set(:"@#{i}reqs", {})
    end

    @reqs[var] = self
  end
end

Klass.new('hello')
```

Remember, the problem was that the instance variables were initialized in one object, and accessed in another. This solution moves the initialization to the same object that was doing the reading.

However, the dual is also possible: move the reading to where the initialized variables are:

```
class Klass
  ['thing', nil].each do |i|
    instance_variable_set(:"@#{i}reqs", {})
  end

  def initialize(var)
    self.class.instance_variable_get(:@reqs)[var] = self
  end
end

Klass.new('hello')
```

This is kind of ugly, so let's add an `attr_reader`:

```
class Klass
  ['thing', nil].each do |i|
    instance_variable_set(:"@#{i}reqs", {})
  end

  class << self; attr_reader :reqs end

  def initialize(var)
    self.class.reqs[var] = self
  end
end

Klass.new('hello')
```

Obviously, these two do very different things. It is unclear from your question which of the two you actually want.

A third possibility would be using class variables:

```
class Klass
  ['thing', nil].each do |i|
    class_variable_set(:"@@#{i}reqs", {})
  end

  def initialize(var)
    @@reqs[var] = self
  end
end

Klass.new('hello')
```

Note that this does yet another different thing. Again, whether you want that or not is not clear from your question.

Comment: Speaking of ugly, doesn't `['thing', nil].each do |i|
    class_variable_set(:"@@#{i}reqs", {}); end` qualify?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Personally, I don't see what's wrong with just `@@thingreqs, @@reqs = {}, {}`, but I wanted to keep the feel of the original code.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder, but I find `class_variable_set(:@@thingreqs, {}); class_variable_set(:@@reqs, {})` cleaner and clearer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: In this particular case, since the names are statically known, and there's only two of them, I don't see any reason to use metaprogramming (i.e. `class_variable_set`) at all, to be honest. Just `@@thingreqs, @@reqs = {}, {}` or `@@thingreqs = {}; @@reqs = {}` or something like that, but like I said, I wanted to keep the feel of the original code. This also makes it obvious that the problem is not with the metaprogramming or the closure property of the `each` block but purely one of dynamic instance scope.

Answer (score 1):

The loop at the top is defining an instance variable for the Class, not for any object of the class.

So for the object, it doesn't exist.

From the looks of it, you want a hash common to the whole class where you store each created object in the hash.  Assuming you don't have issues with class inheritance, you'd be better of with a class variable.

so...

```
class Klass
    ["thing",nil].each do |i|
        class_variable_set("@@#{i}reqs", {})
    end
    def initialize(var)
        @@reqs[var] = self
    end
end
Klass.new("hello")
```

Comment: There's no reason to use class variables here.

Comment: If he wants a hash where a key `name` stores the object itself, that sounds like he wants to store all objects under different names... it's easy to infer that he wants a class variable (or a class-level instance variable)

Answer (score 0):

If you define class like this:

```
class Klass
  instance_variable_set(:@name, 'dog')

  def self.name
    @name
  end

  def name
    @name
  end
end
```

then

```
Klass.name # => 'dog'

instance = Klass.new
instance.name # => nil
```

Now you can see the difference. Your variable is defined on class level, not instance level.